# accessing mongodb remotely? unable to do so

Tags: php-mongodb

I am slightly new to the mongodb scene. what i am trying to do is accessing to my database hosted on MONGOHQ. the page to access it is hosted on a different server and i get the following message every time i visit the web page:

```
> Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in [location] on line 3
```

The question is i tried installing the mongo extension on my php.ini file, is there anything else i should be doing?

The code goes as follows:

```
<?php

$m = new Mongo("mongodb://myusername:mypassword@location.mongolab.com:27419/");
$dbname = "mydata";

// Connect to database
$db = $m->$dbname;


if (isset($_POST['amount'])){
    $mydata->insert(array(
    "name" => $_POST['name'],
    "job" => $_POST['job']
    ));
}   





?>

<form method="POST">
    <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></p>
    <p>Job: <input type="text" name="job"></p>
    <p><button>ADD</button></p>
</form>
```

Comment: anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to install the PHP Mongo drivers on that server that's trying to access MongoHQ or MongoLab. http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php

Comment: drivers were missing indeed.